# CMD Commands won't run in C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, cmd

I'm trying to run the following:

```
String command = @"Rscript C:\Users\someone\Documents\generate_files.R " + fname + " " + folder;

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", "/K PATH C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.1.1\\bin;%path%"); 
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", "/K " + command);
```

Nothing happens when I execute it, does anyone know why? If I try

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", "/K MD TEST");
```

That works fine :s

e: Some extra info, The first command is setting the PATH so that the Rscript can be called by just typing Rscript. Also, both of these commands work when I do them in a normal CMD interface.

Comment: take a look at ProcessStartInfo

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run Command Prompt Commands](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands)

Comment: @ZoomVirus: I don't totally agree. OP seems to have done that already.

Comment: You are starting two different CMD console processes. The first one doesn't share its path with the other one

Comment: That makes sense, is it possible to do one after the other within the same console process? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prepare a batch file and execute it

```
using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("runscript.cmd", false))
{
   sw.WriteLine(@"PATH C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.1\bin;%path%"); 
   sw.WriteLine(@"Rscript C:\Users\someone\Documents\generate_files.R " + fname + " " + folder);
}
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", "/K runscript.cmd");
```

This assumes that you have read/write permissions on the current directory. You can change the location to a more suitable position using

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
string fileCmd = Path.Combine(path, "runscript.cmd");
using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileCmd, false)
....
```

Answer (score 0):

As realised by Steve, I was running two console processes. To resolve this I simply ran both commands in the same process.

Comment: You should (probably) accept Steve's answer, not post one of your own.

Answer (score 0):

cmd.Arguments = "/K \"" + fullFilePath;

*try  double " " right before PATH